# Behavior of SELECT on information_schema.routines based on lower_case_table_names system variable

Tags: mysql, database-schema, collation

This is the query I use to obtain a list of stored procedures in a MySQL database.

```
SELECT `SPECIFIC_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES` WHERE `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = 'database_name' COLLATE utf8_bin AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

I force utf8_bin as the collation to be used in order to get the the correct result if lower_case_table_names system variable is set to 0.

But i get empty resultset with the same query if lower_case_table_names is set to 2 and the database name has uppercase characters.

Also if lower_case_table_names is set to 0 on a system that has case-insensitive file names, I get an empty resultset with the query.

On both these cases, if "COLLATE utf8_bin" is removed from the query or replaced with "COLLATE utf8_general_ci" i get the correct resultset.

Quoting from : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

> - 0
>     Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>     specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name
>     comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0
>     if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file
>     names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you force this variable to 0
>     with --lower-case-table-names=0 on a case-insensitive file system and
>     access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption
>     may result.
> - 1
>     Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are
>     not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on
>     storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and
>     table aliases.
> - 2
>     Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>     specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL
>     converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case
>     sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case
>     sensitive! InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for
>     lower_case_table_names=1.

If lower_case_table_names is set to 2

> "MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup"

What does this mean?

I do know that lower_case_table_names must not be set to 0 on Windows/OS X , but I do not have control on the environment where the query is going to run.

But i find the behavior strange.

SELECT on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS also behaves the same way.

***UPDATE***

Values in ROUTINE_SCHEMA column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table are in lowercase if lower_case_table_names = 2, or when lower_case_table_names = 0 in windows. But ROUTINE_SCHEMA column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES has values with same lettercase as was used when creating the database. Even the resultset from SHOW DATABASES has values with same lettercase as was used when creating the database. Why this difference?

Comment: "*Why this difference?*" - sounds likely to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The value of [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) affects two things:

- the lettercase used for the names of data files stored on disk; and
- implicit transformation of schema object identifiers in SQL commands.

Your problem is that when querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, the only schema object identifiers are the references to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` itself (in your query, the `ROUTINES` table and its column *names*).  References to *your* schema objects (e.g. *values* in the `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` column and your `'database_name'` literal etc.) are not schema object identifiers, but rather ordinary strings (which don't benefit from MySQL's implicit lettercase transformation according to the `lower_case_table_names` system variable).

So, with `lower_case_table_names = 2`, your database is stored on disk (and in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) using the lettercase that was used in the `CREATE DATABASE` command.  If you use a case sensitive collation when querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, the lookups will understandably fail (unless you use the same lettercase as was used when creating the database).  The solution is obviously to use a case insensitive collation, such as `utf8_general_ci`.